# Get the value of data-val after locating element using jQuery [attribute^=value] Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list of `<li>`, each which has a `data-val` attribute.  Example:

`<li data-val="yesterdayTrip">Trip</li>`

Using jQuery `attribute^=value` I can locate a particular `<li>` based on a partial string match and using css can alter the `<li>`.  Such as:

`$("[data-val^='yes']").css("background-color", "yellow");`

But I don't want to turn the background yellow, I want to get the full `data-val` value. The following does not work, although it seems to me that it should:

`var fullValue = $("[data-val^='yes']").getAttribute("data-val");`

How can I get the value for `data-val`?

Comment: when you have `data-val="boo"` in html, just use `$(selector).data('val')` (omit the 'data-' from the attribute name)

Comment: Thank you, yes that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the `data-val` attribute you can use

`$("[data-val^='yes']").data("val")`

or

`$("[data-val^='yes']").attr('data-val')`

either one will get the value. However, if you have multiple selectors match, then it will only get the first one, you'll have to put it in a loop to get all of them.

Comment: This was the first answer and it worked!  Thank you.  It won't let me mark this as the correct answer for another nine minutes.  That is silly.

Comment: Note however will only get value of first matching selector. Since there is a `^=` would presume there may be more than one match

Comment: @charlietfl I have included that in my answer, thank you

Comment: Silly question.  How do I replace the string 'yes' with a variable?

Comment: `$("[data-val^='"+var+"']")`

Comment: Duh.  I am not getting enough sleep.  Obvious.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute data of type data, you should only call the data method that provides jquery, example :

```
$("[data-val^='yes']").data('val');
```

or

```
 $("[data-val^='yes']").attr('data-val');
```